# Load Data from Rest API to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, flume

I have a URL for a `rest api`

```
example: `www.<domainname>/?apikey=1344&host=microsoft.com&records=10 `

example: `www.<domainname>/?apikey=1344&host=timesofindia.com&records=10`
```

The parameters could change

these parameters I get from another file which is a again a JSON format

`["microsoft.com", "cde.com", "timesofindia.com"]`

Can I use flume to load this data, if yes then please advise which source type can be used and how.

If not please advise alternative to it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645260/suggested-hadoop-based-design-component-for-ingestion-of-periodic-rest-api-cal). The link says, you can make use of [ExecSource](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#exec-source)  of flume.